# Sql-DBCC Shrink database not reducing database size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc

I am using SQL Server express edition with 10 GB Size limit, There some table having millions + rows and I need to perform data purging operation at the end of every month, so as to free up the space and make it available for new data storage

If  I use the shrink through SSMS(Right click on database then task then shrink ) it works smoothly and free up the space as expected. 
But the problem arises when I try to achieve the same with

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE

GO

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(MyDatabase)

GO

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET RECOVERY FULL

GO
```

It literally show no effect, infact it increase the log file size but never freeing up the space.Is there any solution,it will be greatly appriciable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would not switch the recovery model to SIMPLE to force shrinking.

When the recovery model is set to FULL you must execute a full backup and at least one transaction log backup to fulfil the recovery condition before you can shrink the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on Database Name and click on **Properties**
2. Options and change on Recovery model from **Full** => **Simple**
3. Starting to shrink again.
4. Check your file log size it's will reduce the size of the database log.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sk5j.png)

Comment: Changing from full to simple has other significant implications - you should expand this answer to include what is being traded-off by making this configuration change.